# Sitecore User Group - Budapest #8

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**About the event:**

The 8th Hungarian Sitecore User Group has been announced! This meetup is going to be international! 4 presentations with 4 presenters from 3 countries! They will talk about the following topics:

- How to start SPEAK3 if you are a backend developer - Mihály Árvai (@POSSIBLE & Sitecore Hackathon award winner)
- 10x Your Sitecore development - Mark Cassidy (@Cassidy Consult & Sitecore Technology MVP)
- Experiences with Sitecore XC and some do's and dont's - Christian Hahn (@Freelancer & Sitecore Commerce MVP)
- From code to server: Case study in a programmer doing CI/CD - Bence Juhos (@ALLWIN & Sitecore Developer)

Free conversations, food and drink after the presentations.

**When (UTC):** Thursday, May 16, 2019 5:30 PM

**Where:** Accenture Hungary, Bence utca 1., Budapest

**[RSVP to this Event](https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Budapest/events/260076257/)**

Comment: Fixed the date. Community Bulletin promotion begins on May 6 at 17:30